# How to rank values in different columns based on a criteria in Python (transferring Excel calculations to Python)?

Tags: python, excel, rank

I have a workbook in Excel with a bunch of calculations, but the file is getting too large and the calculations are taking too long to finish in Excel so I am trying to move the file to another program (preferably Python) to handle the calculations. I only have basic experience with Python, so I'm not even sure if this is the best software to handle this calculation.

Anyways, the below is the table I am working with (this is a smaller version of the actual table; the actual table has over 35,000 rows).

```html
State Item # Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4 Val5 Rank1 Rank2 Rank3 Rank4 Rank5 Count
CA   1     5.55 4.16 3.12 2.34 1.76 2     5     8     11     14     2
CA   2     6.43 4.82 3.62 2.71 2.03 1     3     6     9     12     2
CA   3     4.79 3.59 2.69 2.02 1.52 4     7     10     13     15     1
FL   4     10.41 7.81 5.86 4.39 3.29 1     3     5     7     9     3
FL   5     8.02 6.02 4.51 3.38 2.54 2     4     6     8     11     2
FL   6     3.22 2.42 1.81 1.36 1.02 10     12     13     14     15     0
NY   7     0.97 0.73 0.55 0.41 0.31 8     10     12     14     15     0
NY   8     1.44 1.08 0.81 0.61 0.46 6     7     9     11     13     0
NY   9     14.31 10.73 8.05 6.04 4.53 1     2     3     4     5     5
WA   10     9.31 6.98 5.24 3.93 2.95 1     3     5     7     9     3
WA   11     8.91 6.68 5.01 3.76 2.82 2     4     6     8     10     2
WA   12     1.55 1.16 0.87 0.65 0.49 11     12     13     14     15     0
```

The columns State, Item #, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, and Val5 are my input data. What I need to do is find the top 5 values by each state, and count up how many of the top 5 values each item # has. I have done the calculations in Excel in the Rank1-Rank5 and Count columns. I'm wondering if this can be done in Python, and if so, how? I also want the code to be flexibile to allow me to add in more "Val" columns (might go up to 10 values).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when working with tabular data in Python, the pandas library is a good tool to reach for.  There are lots of ways to do what you want, IIUC, but here's one which shouldn't be too hard to follow.  It's mostly to give you a sense for the kinds of thing you can do.  Starting from a DataFrame looking like yours:

```
>>> df
   State  Item #   Val1   Val2  Val3  Val4  Val5
0     CA       1   5.55   4.16  3.12  2.34  1.76
1     CA       2   6.43   4.82  3.62  2.71  2.03
2     CA       3   4.79   3.59  2.69  2.02  1.52
3     FL       4  10.41   7.81  5.86  4.39  3.29
4     FL       5   8.02   6.02  4.51  3.38  2.54
5     FL       6   3.22   2.42  1.81  1.36  1.02
6     NY       7   0.97   0.73  0.55  0.41  0.31
7     NY       8   1.44   1.08  0.81  0.61  0.46
8     NY       9  14.31  10.73  8.05  6.04  4.53
9     WA      10   9.31   6.98  5.24  3.93  2.95
10    WA      11   8.91   6.68  5.01  3.76  2.82
11    WA      12   1.55   1.16  0.87  0.65  0.49
```

we can (1) turn it so the data is all vertical, (2) rank them so that low numbers are associated with the highest scores (with lots of options for how to handle ties; I'm ignoring those issues), (3) decide which ones we're interested in, and (4) count them by State/Item # combination.  (In principle I guess an item could belong to more than one state, in which case we'd just drop the State from that last groupby).

```
df_m = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["State", "Item #"], var_name="Value")
df_m["rank"] = df_m.groupby("State")["value"].rank(ascending=False)
df_m["top"] = rank <= 5
df_m.groupby(["State", "Item #"], as_index=False)["top"].sum()
```

which finally produces

```
   State  Item #  top
0     CA       1    2
1     CA       2    2
2     CA       3    1
3     FL       4    3
4     FL       5    2
5     FL       6    0
6     NY       7    0
7     NY       8    0
8     NY       9    5
9     WA      10    3
10    WA      11    2
11    WA      12    0
```

That's simply a melt (a kind of pivot operation); a groupby; a rank; a comparison; another groupby; and a sum (True == 1, so summing booleans is a count).  Might be a bit scary for a complete beginner, but hopefully it'll encourage you to give pandas a try, because with just a bit of experience you can do a lot of operations quite efficiently.

Comment: DSM, this is really helpful tutorial! I was wondering if you could refer me to the other ways of doing this that you mentioned in your response. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)  is probably the best tool for this kind of task. Start [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html). There are many online tutorials and YouTube videos about it. For example, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w26x-z-BdWQ) is by the original author himself.